# Unique style only for outbound links pointing to a certain website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to assign underline CSS rule for outbound affiliate backlinks that are pointing to a certain website. Each of these backlinks is unique, but the root domain is the same. Tried some suggestions found here, but none of them work.

```
a[href^="cochrane.org"] {
text-decoration:underline!important;
}
```

Comment: you need the `*` card character : you should try  `a[href*="cochrane.org"] {
text-decoration:underline!important;
}`

Comment: `^=` this means that all links have to start with `"cochrane.org"`. 
`*=` which G-Cyr recommended means that links just contain it.

Answer (score 1):

use `a[href*="cochrane.org"]` instead of `a[href^="cochrane.org"]` it will works or try below code

```css
a{
text-decoration:none;
}

a[href*="cochrane.org"] {
text-decoration:underline!important;
}
```

```html
<a href="test.com" >Link One</a>
<a href="test.com" >Link Two</a>
<a href="https://www.cochrane.org/" >cochrane Home Page</a>
<a href="test.com" >Link Three</a>
<a href="https://www.cochrane.org/news" >cochrane News</a>
```